# Path finding between models in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, path-finding

I am trying to make a graph like structure in django using models to create paths between model instances.

But I am no quite sure about how to do that automatically.

The basic structure of my models is something like this:

```
class Location(TimeStampedModel):
   name = models.Charfield()
   level = models.SmallPositiveIntegerField()
   previous_locations = models.ForeignKey('self')
   next_locations = models.ForeignKey('self')
   related_locations = models.ForeignKey('self')
```

That `previous_locations`, `next_locations` and `related_locations` were my first approach in order to get some kind of tree structure, but they are pretty useless when there are several locations with the same level. For example, location_1 (with level = 1) can go to location_2 and location_3 (both with level = 2) and then both can go to location_4 (with level = 4).

Maybe changing the foreign key to a many to many relation can solve this, but it's still not clear to my how to create the paths.

For the paths, I made the following model:

```
class Path(TimeStampedModel):
   name = models.Charfield()
   locations = models.ManyToManyField(Locations)
```

Summarizing, the goal is select two locations and automatically create the shortest path or a group of paths (as maybe 2 paths require the same amount of steps). However, I don't know how to doit with the relations I currently have.

I am open to some ideas but I don't want to modify my models too much.

Does some "tree graph" model exist for django? Maybe there's something to which I can say "Hey, take those locations with those levels and those relations between them and create a graph and give me that sweet shortest path" but I don't know about it.

If it does not exist: Can someone guide me on how to make an algorithm to find the shortest path between those locations?

To show an example of exactly what I want to do with my models, here we have an image. The shortest path from 1 to 7 is 1, 3, 7. But from 1 to 8 there are two equally large paths. And I want to be able to go from 5 to 7 (that's why I have related location). How can I automatically do it?

Not asking for code, just give me a hint or a place where I can read. Thanks!

Comment: Hey. Unless you really want to I would suggest to look into existing libraries for pathfinding. One of the most popular is: https://networkx.org/